# mod_rewrite: can a back reference be referenced twice?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule (in an Apache htaccess file) which is attempting to use a back reference twice from just one capture ($1):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?nav=$1
```

It appears that the query string is being left emtpy, like

```
example.com/new
```

is being re-written as

```
example.com/new.php?nav=
```

what I want is

```
example.com/new.php?nav=new
```

My question: can I reference $1 twice in the expression?

**UPDATE:**

The Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) on mod_rewrite indicates that you can reference a capture as many times as you like in the substitution part of a rewrite rule. However, after trying for a couple of days I was not able to make it work. I did get my rule to pass in the online regex testers that are out there, but not on my site. In the end I re-designed my menu system so that I could use simpler rewrite rules.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't see why you _wouldn't_ be able to, since in every other implementation of regular expressions, this is possible. I'm curious, what happens if you used ^((A-Za-z0-9-_))$ instead, then `$1` and `$2`? If this works, that would more strongly isolate the problem to what you suggest.

Comment: Thanks. Tried $2, but the problem remains.

Comment: Actually, that's a useful hint! The fact that that doesn't work hints that this _doesn't_ have much to do with using the backreference twice. Something else is going on.

Comment: All my other rules work fine. This is the only one where I'm trying to 're-use' the back reference, which seems totally logical. It's the only thing I can see that is different from the other rules.

Comment: This may be the only one reusing the backreference, but that may only be a coincidence. The alternate example, which you said did not work, demonstrates that it's not _only_ the repeated-backreference case that failed: using _separate_ backreferences failed too. Try `$1$1.php?nav=$1` for your replacement string, to see what I mean. I believe in that example, you _will_ see the repeated backreference work, just not in the query string, and further my belief is that there's an issue with your _query_ string, not related to the backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

This regex that your're using is wrong:

```
^(A-Za-z0-9-_)$
```

Range is allowed in square brackets only and your need to use `+` accessor to match more than 1 character.

Replace your RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?nav=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right, but the same problem remains. The query string still missing.

Comment: I had already tested this rule and it is working fine. Most likely you have some other rule or script that is stripping your query string.